# How do I call a function once after all chrome.cookies.onChange events fire?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

how do I call a function once after all cookies.onChange events fire, I kown

```
chrome.cookies.onChange.addListener
```

but it call event handler everytime after every cookies get changed, I want to call event handler only once after all events fired.

How I can do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var hasBeenCalled = false;
    function doSomethingOnce() {
       if (!called) {
          console.log("I haven't been called before");
          // do fancy stuff.
          hasBeenCalled = true;
       } else {
          // do nothing, function already called.

       };
    };

chrome.cookies.onChange.addListener(doSomethingOnce);
```

Or better yet, you can probably find a `chrome.cookies.onChange.removeListener(doSomethingOnce);`,
in which case inside your `doSomethingOnce` function, after you do whatever you want to do, you call `chrome.cookies.onChange.removeListener(doSomethingOnce);`